# How to enable escaping in symfony 1.4 application with Apostrophe plugin?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, apostrophe

In our application we need to enable escaping. But is there some way to enable escaping in whole application, except Apostrophe modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apostrophe 1.5 is compatible with the Symfony default escaping strategy..

settings.yml

```
all:
  .settings:
    escaping_strategy: true
    escaping_method: ESC_SPECIALCHARS
```